# Image: I need 100% height to be more important than 100% width

Tags: css, image, height, responsive

Basically I have an image that needs to stay 100% height no matter the screen size, so its responsive, and its ok to cut off the left and right sides (just not the top and bottom).

I currently have the image set to be responsive for both height and width, but at certain widths and heights it cuts the top and bottom off the image.

Here is my CSS:

```
.banner{
    width:36%;
    float:left;
    min-height: 100vh;
    height: 100%;
}

.banner img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

PHP (Wordpress):

```
<div class="banner">    
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

take away object-fit and change with to auto:

```
.banner img {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

or object-fill, but that can skew the picture, are you sure you don't want it as a background image? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I change the height to 100% then the image isn't vertically responsive any longer and the width sets on the height of the image.
Examples of what happens: https://imgur.com/HYA84sE & https://imgur.com/zhSVjNm